# C++ function declaration

Tags: c++, function

I was looking into some C++ tutorial and encountered a function declaration inside the class

```
class CRectangle {
    int x, y;
public:
    int area (void)  {return x*y;}
};
```

Now I am wondering what is the use of `void` after int area?

Comment: It simply means that the function takes no argument. Also second pair of parentheses should be {}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void` in this case means that the function doesn't take any parameters.

Also - syntax error, you probably meant `{}` brackets and you had the semicolon in the wrong place.

```
int area (void){ return (x*y); }
```

Comment: yeah ,  But is it mandatory to mention void if function doesn't take parameter?? normally in c we never do that

Comment: It's not mandatory. Actually, in C, if you *don't* use `void`, it means it's a varargs function that can take a differnt # of parameters.

Comment: Actually, if you don't explicitely write "void", that means that your function may take an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: @samprat: In C++, omitting `void`, for example `()`, in a function declaration is the same as `(void)`.  In C, omitting void means K&R semantics.

Answer (score 3):

The void parameter type is unnecessary in C++. A function declared with an empty argument list is equivalent. The reason it's legal is to allow C code to compile without error.

The void parameter type is necessary in C because a function declared with an empty argument list accepts any number of any typed arguments. This is a remnant of pre-ANSI C, also known as K&R C. K&R C did not require function prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

This code is invalid. It should be (also changed whitespace to be more clear, but the issue is not about it)

```
int area(void) { return (x * y); }
```

`int area(void)` is the member function signature — `int` is the returned type, `(void)` means an empty argument list. It's a C-ism, and shouldn't be used in C++ — `int area()` means the same thing.